# What are hexadecimal function in lua?

Tags: function, debugging, lua

When I do debug.getinfo for debugging a script, it return an function in a hexadeximal number as follow on the func field:

```
function: 0xa02c196dd610cfa6,
```

I am wondering what are function in hexadecima and how can I use the debug library with these function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated on [this](https://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/debug.getinfo) page, `debug.getinfo` returns a table, not a function.

The table returned by `debug.getinfo` contains information like the name of the given function, if one can be found; the current line of the given function; and the number of upvalues, that is, the number of local variables the given function has access to. These are important pieces of information when debugging.

To inspect the information contained in the table returned by `debug.getinfo`, try the following code:

```
function foo()
   -- `1' refers to the current layer of the call stack, that is, this very function.
   return debug.getinfo(1)
end

t = foo()
for k, v in pairs(foo) do
    print(k, v)
end
```

Also, with regard to your question about hexadecimal addresses of functions: given that Lua is a memory-safe language--which is to say that it does not allow for direct access to memory--having the address of a function means little. A function takes up a certain space in memory, and the hexadecimal address of a function refers to the first byte it occupies in memory. In Lua, functions are first-class variables, meaning that they can be passed around like numbers, strings, etc.; so, unlike C/C++ and similar languages, there are no function pointers. Thus, having the hexadecimal address of a function does not allow you to do anything special.

Comment: I would recommend reading the section of the Lua manual about the debug library. If you are interested in the Lua stack, I would recommend reading about Lua's C API.